# Is the file style wrong? and how to adding the sum

Tags: sum, element, addition

I am new as Python learning.
created a txt file contains series of numbers:
TXT Style A: 1, 3, 4, 2, 22, 11, ...,32
TXT Style B: 1 3 4 2 22...32
both txt files can be opened. I failed to add the sum of the values.
Question 1: Does the text style with ',' affect the adding function?
Question 2: How can I get each value and calculate the sum?

with open('numbers.txt', 'r') as f:

```
numbers_line = f.read()
print(numbers_line)
x = numbers_line.split()
#print(len(x))
```

def number():

```
i = len(x)
# Learn different methods to retrieve element
#s = int(x.__getitem__(25))
s = int(x[25])
w = int(x[24])
# Able to retrieve element, but this is not the way to program
# needed advice and corrections
print(i, s, w, s + w)
```

number()

f.close()

Comment: I have numbers.txt file, contains int from 1 to 32 (with 25 numbers there)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the text style with ',' affect the adding function?

Before we can get to the adding, it does affect the splitting, since `str.split()` if no delimiter is specified splits only at whitespace. To split at comma and whitespace as well, you can

```
import re
…
    x = re.split("[,\s]+", numbers_line)
```

> How can I get each value and calculate the sum?

You already used the `int` function to convert a string to an integer (although with `int(x[25])` you missed that the indexes range from 0 to 24); you could apply `int` to each string of `x` with the `map` function, and you can calculate the sum with the `sum` function:

```
    print(sum(map(int, x)))
```